# Python Regex remove numbers and numbers with punctaution

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
 line = "1234567 7852853427.111 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(disambiguation)"
```

I would like to remove the numbers 1234567 7852853427.111 using regular expresisions

I have this re

```
nline = re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d\w\d|\s\d+$", " ", line)
```

but it is not doing what i hoped it would be doing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A few loose remarks on *why* your attempt did not work: the start anchor seems correct, but that end anchor does not. It's not the end of the string, by far! Also, **all** of those `|` split the entire regex into distinct parts - that is, the first part matches the start of the string but the second one does not. You may want to read up on creating groups with parentheses.

Comment: Where is this string coming from? HTML parsing?..

Comment: Most of the current suggestions more or less kill every sequence of digits inside the string. Can you be reasonably sure that there never will be digits in the part you want to keep? How about removing "the first two words"? Or "everything before `http://`"? Your title mentions *punctuation* - should `1..2` at the beginning be removed?

Comment: If your regex requirements are not strict, better to use built-in solution. For current line `line.split()[-1]`, which is much easier.

Comment: @RadLexus I think there will be digits in the url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> line = "1234567 7852853427.111 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(disambiguation)" 
>>> print re.sub(r'\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+', '', line)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(disambiguation)
```

Regex `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+` will match an integer or decimal number followed by 1 or more spaces. `\b` is for word boundary.

Comment: An anchor at the start would be a bit safer :)

Comment: `\b` will work but `^` won't because `7852853427.111` is not at the start.

Comment: Ah, because you consider each number separately. I was wondering why - perhaps OP needs to clarify or add more than one example. I was actually thinking of something as straightforward as `^[\d.\s]+` ...

Comment: @RadLexus think this solution will strip the numbers which appear in the URL. I need the numbers in the url to be intact

Comment: @Morpheus: Try my updated answer now. It shouldn't affect numbers in URL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-regex approach, if your regex requirement is not entirely strict, using [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> ''.join(dropwhile(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), line))
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(disambiguation)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
nline = re.sub("\d+\s\d+\.\d+", "", line)
```

It removes the numbers from line. If you want to keep the space in front of "http..." your second parameter should of course be " ".

If you also want to record the individual number strings you could put them in groups like this:

```
>>> result = re.search("(\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+)", line)
>>> print(result.group(0))
1234567 7852853427.111
>>> print(result.group(1))
1234567
>>> print(result.group(2))
7852853427.111
```

A great way to learn and practice regular expressions is [regex101](http://regex101.com).

Answer (score 0):

Though you are asking for a regular expression, a better solution would be to use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), assuming that your string will always be in the format `{number} {number} {hyperlink}`.

As @godaygo [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582859/python-regex-remove-numbers-and-numbers-with-punctaution#comment66476693_39582859), you can use this:

```
line = line.split()[-1]
```

The string will be split on whitespace, and we select the last substring.

If you want to access all parts (assuming there's always three), you can use this instead:

```
num1, num2, url = line.split()
```